# How to negotiate a salary in Norway/Scandinavian countries?

Tags: phd, interview, salary, europe, negotiation

So, my application looks like its going very well. I've got a feedback from the Norwegian institute that I am the most suitable candidate for the job among 13 ones. In a few weeks, I will be in the interview. I examine that there will be salary negotiations after the interview, taken into account the hard processing for all the applicants to the job and the committee's decision to choose me as the best candidate.

The salary pay scale is 57-76 according to the Norwegian system. To be honest, anything less than 68 will not be of interest to me. However, I don't want to lose the job because of such decision.
I don't find any information on here or the internet about how can I negotiate a salary in Academic Norwegian organizations.

I would appreciate your help or experience. PS: I have a family, maybe this can explain why I need a higher pay :P

Thank you.

Comment: I don't have any Scandinavian specific negotiation advice but in general you should focus on your qualifications and what someone with those qualifications is worth in your specific job market.  Rather than justifying your salary based on non job factors.  I have seen those used more often in other areas of compensation than salary. i.e "I have 4 weeks of vacation at my current job, I know your standard is 3 but is there any way I can get 4? lower salary perhaps?"   Or "I just completed my graduate degree with my current employer, I need a signing bonus to pay them back for their tuition."

Comment: Hi and thank you for your reply. I don't believe this can be the case in Norway. I have never read something like that. Cause, equality is a standard to them, but playing around would be with the pay scale. However, it worth a try when negotiation comes.

Comment: Two questions / comments: (1) is this for a faculty position or for a soft-money position (PhD student or postdoc?)? Negotiating in the former case is *very* hard, as the funding usually accounts for a specific salary and it's not clear where a higher salary would actually come from. (2) you should not *expect* to be selected prior to interviews, and you should definitely not start to negotiate before you have an offer.

Comment: I have tagged this [tag:europe] --- I am not sure if we need to create a more specific geographical tag though.

Comment: `To be honest, anything less than 68 will not be of interest to me. However, I don't want to lose the job because of such decision.`  Those statements are completely at odds with each other.

Comment: Hi @xLeitix, this is a researcher position - (better than postdoc) so, it's not PhD nor postdoc. but, I thank you for your last statement, "don't negotiate before the offer!" and finally yes, "dont expect anything before the selection". but at least, asking the question is important before being in that situation :-)

Comment: @NotMe, you know when you have that feeling that you dont want to lose the job but you want the maximum benefits? this is what i am trying to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm a PhD student, born and raised in Denmark. I have not applied for jobs in Norway, but have done some teaching in Norway and had a few interactions with Norwegian academics.

The Norwegians will appreciate humbleness, good manners and honesty. In the culture, it is very acceptable to care for your family. 
In all communications in particular, good manners is key.

My recommended approach: Be humble and grateful for their offer, state all the reasons why you really want to work with them, then, without overdoing this (remain humble) state all the reasons that you are valuable. Then, proceed with honesty: state that you want to be at their workplace, how much you want to get paid, that you have some experience and that you need some funding to support your family.

Wish you luck!